# fatal error: sys/syslimits.h file not found

Tags: android, android-ndk

While using ndk-build to build that `Android-ImageMagick` repo, I got the error in the title. Apparently the C file that sparked that error has that as a dependency.

I've heard that reinstalling the NDK would work. Well, it didn't work for me, but I know it exists in `F:/android-ndk-r17b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/include-fixed/syslimits.h`.

Do I have to put that in a folder named 'sys' or something?

Answer (score 0):

`<syslimits.h>` is a GCC specific header (and the one on my Debian system can't even be included directly). The project should not be including that directly, but instead should include `<limits.h>`.

Comment: I think the same error popped up when I was compiling OpenCV with CMake and MinGW-32, and in both cases I used the android-ndk-r17b version of the NDK. The strange thing is that I managed to not trigger the error by downgrading the NDK used to android-ndk-r13b. Is it just me, or is NDK weird like that?

Comment: You were probably using GCC in the older NDK.